# the OR function always trips me up

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've always had trouble with this one over the years!  I don't seem able to get the OR function in Excel to work.
In my model, the cell E46 should contain either a valid Postcode or the value "none".  Unfortunately I have also encountered  a "#value" in E46 so have written the following formula to trap this error and return "None" if encountered:

```
=IF(OR(E46="None",ISERROR(E46)),"None",VLOOKUP(E46, List,2,FALSE))
```

Trouble is, I still get `#value` returned by this formula when `E46` contains `#value` even though I think I am trapping it!

All the help texts suggest I have written the formula correctly – I cannot see what I am doing wrong.  Any helpful suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use OR when there might be an error in there (because the OR function will give an error in that case - from E46="None" part), try trapping the error first with nested IFs, e.g.

`=IF(ISERROR(E46),"None",IF(E46="None",E46,VLOOKUP(E46, List,2,FALSE)))`

You'd still get an error if E46 isn't in List......

If you have Excel 2007 or greater you can use IFERROR like

`=IFERROR(IF(E46="None",E46,VLOOKUP(E46, List,2,FALSE)),"None")`

Comment: With thanks to brettdj for the edits and most sincere thanks to barry houdini for the solution.  Like so many, I guess, it becomes obvious when you know the answer (less clear when you don't).